# A databound datagridview on update doesn't display the top rows

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, datagridview

When new rows are added to the `datasource` the `datagridview` updates but the rows that are automatically in view i.e. don't need to be scrolled to are 'old' rows. The previously selected row is at the bottom of the viewable rows. I want the newest rows to be displayed i.e. the scroll bar to always be at the top.

I've tried de-selecting all the rows in the `datagridview`:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
```

And although no row is selected the rows at the top of the `datagridview` aren't automatically displayed. The `datagridview` still jumps to display the previously selected row.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```